# C++ разница между массивами

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Есть два массива:

- `char *str`
- `char* str[]`

По своему принципу, это просто одномерный массив, но при этом, я не могу добавить никаких значений во второй. 
Вопрос: какая между ними тогда разница? Зачем объявлять их именно в таком виде и какой от этого плюс?

**Update**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас массив константных строк. Вам нужен `const char* strs[] = {"Hello", "world"};`

Comment: @Arhad. так работает. спасибо. 
блин, три года работаю уже на джаве, а не могу с массивами в С++ разобраться.

Comment: Дело не в массивах. В Си и C++ константной (immutable, final) может быть любая переменная. В случае же указателей константность можно навесить не только на сам указатель, но и на доступ к тому, на что он указывает. Вот мы и объявляем массив указателей как `const char * strs[]`, то есть **не**константный массив указателей на константные строки.

Comment: Делаем мы так потому, что любая строковая *константа* (вида `"..."`) имеет тип `const char[...]`, то есть константный массив. Вот у вас и возникла изначальная  ошибка из-за попытки присвоить константу туда,  где допустимо изменять значения.

Comment: @Arhad а как тогда выглядит *константный массив указателей на константные строки* ? `const const char* str[]`?

Comment: Нет. Это будет `const char * const str[]` — звёздочка указателя как бы разделяет объявление на две части. Левая относится к указываемому типу, а правый — к указывающему (т. е. непосредственно указателю). Кстати, благодаря этому выражения  `const char * foo` и `char const * foo` полностью аналогичны. И ещё момент: пробелы вокруг звёздочки не имеют значения, они чисто для читаемости.

Comment: @Arhad очень полезная информация. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `char* str[]` (с пустыми квадратными скобками) — при использовании в качестве аргумента функции при её объявлении это то же самое, что и `char **str`.

  Как это дело трактовать — зависит исключительно от логики кода:

  - Это может быть указатель на массив указателей (тогда можно сделать что-то наподобие `char *foo = str[16];`). Причём элементы массива могут указывать как на начало нуль-терминированных строк, так и на отдельные символы, хранящиеся где-то в другом месте.
  - Это может быть просто указатель на `char*`-переменную, позволяющий модифицировать саму эту переменную отовсюду, куда мы передали этот указатель.
  - Это может быть двумерный массив типа `char`. Такой массив называется *jagged* и, в отличие от традиционного, позволяет хранить разное количество элементов в каждой строке (если первый индекс обозначает номер строки) или столбце (если первый индекс обозначает номер столбца)
- `char* str[N]` (с некой константой в скобках) — это уже полноценный массив фиксированной длины, хранящий в себе N элементов типа `char *`.

  Однако в данном случае есть три важных момента:

  1. Это работает только при объявлении переменных. Если вы попытаетесь указать подобную конструкцию в качестве аргумента функции при её объявлении, содержимое квадратных скобок будет проигнорировано, и вы получите первый случай.
  2. Если вы совмещаете объявление массива с его заполнением (`char* str = {...}`), константу N можно опустить, тогда её значение будет вычислено автоматически.
  3. В C++ значение N должно быть именно константой, в противном случае вы получите ошибку компиляции. Массивы переменной длины разрешены только в Си не ранее C99.

Comment: *"char* str[] (с пустыми квадратными скобками) — это то же самое, что и char **str"* - только если это параметр в функции. В других случаях это полноценный массив фиксированной длины. Трактовка в каждом случае всегда однозначная.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо за уточнение, исправил.

Answer (score 7):

Первый - *указатель* на `char`, второй - массив указателей на `char`. Ну, или, *грубо* говоря - первое - это C-строка, второе - массив указетелей на эти строки (но не сами данные).

Примерно так:

```
char * str;
str = new char[20];
strcpy(str, "Hello, world\n");
cout << str;
delete[] str;

const char* strs[] = { "Hello", "world" };
for(auto s: strs)
    cout << s << endl;
```

Comment: вот я пробовал добавить элементы так же, как в примере ниже и у меня ошибка компиляции. Добавил скрин в update. 
При этом пробовал что-то типа: 
`const char *str = "hello";  char* strs[5]; strs[0] = str;`. 
Но все равно ошибка.

Comment: грубо говорять это получается тогда двумерный массив?

Comment: Да, если грубо :)

Comment: К вашему *Update* - сделайте, например, так: `char* strs[] = {(char*) "Hello", (char*)"world" };`. Или `const char* strs[] = { "Hello", "world" };` Хотя многим компиляторам плевать - см., например, https://ideone.com/VmLMAl

Answer (score 5):

В первом случае у вас просто указатель на `char`, а вот второй случай интереснее и совершенно не равен первому.

`char *str[]` - это массив указателей на `char`. Тобишь его можно представлять как массив строк (что не совсем верно, но в общем случае можно и так). Тобишь если хотите чтобы указатель из массива указывал на нужную вам строку нужно что-то вроде:

```
char alfa[] = "alfa";
char beta[] = "beta";
char *str[2];
str[0] = alfa;
str[1] = beta;
```

Comment: если можно создать массив как `char *alfa = ...` так и `char alfa[] =...`, получается, что в случае массивов `[]` тоже самое что и указатель `*`?

Comment: @DimaKhodan не совсем, тут немного сложнее: дело в том, что `char *alfa` это явно указатель, но `char alfa[]` - это массив символов (именно поэтому нельзя указателю прямо задать литерал, а массиву можно). При этом `char alfa[]` неявно приводится к указателю на `char`, поэтому `alfa` можно юзать как `char * const`. ВАЖНО!! Если указатель (не помеченный как `* const`) можно изменять, то вот с массивом уже такое не прокатит, так как массив неявно приводится именно к `char * const`.

Answer (score 3):

Первое это указатель на `char`, а второе в зависимости от контекста может быть
 либо массивом указателей, либо указателем на указатель (если это тип аргумента функции).