# Значение типа const char* нельзя присвоить сущности типа char*

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Form
{
    int Age;
    int Sex;        /* 0 - мужчина; 1 - женщина */
    int Education; /* 0 - начальное; 1 - среднее; 2 - высшее */
    int Question;   /* 0 - НЕТ; 1 - ДА */
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int     Selection, i;
    struct Form    *pForm = NULL;
    int     RecCount = 0;
    int     k1, k2, k3;
    char    *str;

    printf("M E N U\n-------------------\n");
    printf("1. Dobavit zapis\n");
    printf("2. Analiz anket\n");
    printf("3. Vivod anket\n");
    printf("4. Vihod");

    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n\nVash vibor: ");
        scanf("%d ", &Selection);

        switch (Selection)
        {
        case 1: /* Dobavit zapis */
            pForm = (struct Form*)realloc(pForm, (RecCount + 1) * sizeof(struct Form));

            printf("\nVvedite dannye:\n");
            printf("\tVozrast: ");
            scanf("%d", &pForm[RecCount].Age);
            printf("\tPol (0 - M; 1 - G): ");
            scanf("%d", &pForm[RecCount].Sex);
            printf("\tObrazovanie (0 - nach.; 1 - sr.; 2 - vishee): ");
            scanf("%d", &pForm[RecCount].Education);
            printf("\tVi kurite? (0 - NET; 1 - DA): ");
            scanf("%d", &pForm[RecCount].Question);

            RecCount++;
            break;
        case 2: /* Analiz anket */
            k1 = k2 = k3 = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < RecCount; i++)
            {
                if (pForm[i].Sex == 0 &&   /* muzhchina.*/
                    pForm[i].Age > 40 &&  /* starshe 40 let.*/
                    pForm[i].Education == 2 &&   /* имеющий высшее образование...*/
                    pForm[i].Question == 1)  /* ответивший ДА.*/
                    k1++;
                if (pForm[i].Sex == 1 &&     /* женщина.*/
                    pForm[i].Age < 30 &&    /* моложе 30 лет...*/
                    pForm[i].Education == 1 &&  /* имеющая среднее образование... */
                    pForm[i].Question == 0)   /* ответившая НЕТ. */
                    k2++;
                if (pForm[i].Sex == 0 &&      /* мужчина... */
                    pForm[i].Age < 25 &&  /* моложе 25 лет.*/
                    pForm[i].Education == 0 &&   /* имеющий начальное образование... */
                    pForm[i].Question == 1)   /* ответивший ДА... */
                    k3++;
            }
            printf("\nStatistika #1: %d\n", k1);
            printf("Statistika #2: %d\n", k2);
            printf("Statistika #3: %d\n", k3);
            break;
        case 3: /* Вывод всех анкет */
            printf("\nVse ankety:\n");
            printf("====================================================\n");
            printf("Vozrast      Pol          Obrazovanie         Otvet\n");
            printf("====================================================\n");
            for (i = 0; i < RecCount; i++)
            {
                if (pForm[i].Education == 0)
                    str = "Nachalnoe";
                else if (pForm[i].Education == 1)
                    str = "Srednee  ";
                else
                    str = "Vishee   ";

                printf("%d           %s            %s           %s\n", pForm[i].Age,
                    ((pForm[i].Sex) ? "G" : "M"),
                    str,
                    ((pForm[i].Question) ? "DA" : "NET"));
                printf("____________________________________________________\n");
            }
        }
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

в фрагменте

```
if (pForm[i].Education == 0)
    str = "Nachalnoe";
else if (pForm[i].Education == 1)
    str = "Srednee  ";
else
    str = "Vishee   ";
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [C++ разница между массивами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/857615/208074).

Answer (score 7):

У вас объявлено

```
char    *str;
```

Т.е. `str` указывает на *изменяемую* строку. А тут, например

```
str = "Nachalnoe";
```

вы присваиваете константную строку (каковой является строковый литерал). Каковую компилятор имеет право разместить где-нибудь в памяти только для чтения - и как тогда выполнить что-то вроде `str[0] = 'X';`? (Раз вы объявили `char*`, значит, намерены изменять строку. Если не намерены - то объявляйте `const char * str;`)